# How to fit a xbar with equal width

Tags: floats

I want to draw a crisp xbar in latex. The image I am generating does not have an equal width and does not name all the y-labels. What am I doing wrong?

[image]

```
\begin{figure}
\begin{center}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{axis} [
xbar,
symbolic y coords = {{Apples},{Oranges},{Bananas},{Grapes},{Strawberries},{Blueberries}},
ytick= data,
nodes near coords,
nodes near coords align = {horizontal}
]

\addplot [draw=black, fill=cyan!40!black] coordinates {
(1, {Apples}) (2, {Oranges}) (5, {Bananas}) (10, {Grapes}) (100, {Strawberries}) (1000, {Blueberries})
};
\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{center}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: Please extend your code snippet to a complete small document, which we can compile as it is.

Comment: Any news? Does my answer help you?

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}
\centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
title={Test: monocolor},
xbar,
ytick distance=1,   % <---
title={Tex example},
nodes near coords,
symbolic y coords = {Apples,Oranges,Bananas,
                     Grapes,Strawberries,Blueberries},
xmin=0,
enlarge x limits={0.2, upper} % <---
            ]
\addplot [fill=cyan!40!black] coordinates {(1,Apples)  (2,Oranges)        (5,Bananas)
                                           (10,Grapes) (100,Strawberries) (1000,Blueberries)
                                            };
\end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Mine difference to your code snipped is in code marked by `% <---`. You always should consider errors when compile your code.

[image]